Add to chart error
In a recently created SFCC sandbox org, I am trying to add a product in my chart and receiving the error on the console:
[
{
"errorCode": "ILLEGAL_QUERY_PARAMETER_VALUE",
"message": "Argument: account '0010700000o3GvP' does not belong to webstore '0ZE07000000sfTy'."
}
]

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
